# Change Navigation Controller's Toolbar Animation in setToolbarHidden:animated:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I wanted to change the animation that occurs on a navigationControllers toolbar when the method setToolbarHidden is called. By default, when you set Hidden to YES and animation to YES, the toolbar simply drops off the screen. I'd like it to slide off the screen from left to right (much like when you hit the back button on a navbar and the previous view controller reasserts itself on the screen). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a bug report and it appears, unfortunately, there isn't a way to do this until Apple adds the feature themselves.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be perfect but it might be possible with something like this:

```
       self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;    
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinished:finished:context:)];

        CGRect frame = self.navigationController.toolbar.frame;
        frame.origin.x = -1*frame.size.width;
        self.navigationController.toolbar.frame = frame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];

- (void)animationFinished:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context {
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
}
```